# Numpy array not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

So I wrote this python program in which a part of it is it behaving as i would like to. Where am I going wrong? Any rectification suggested will be most obliged.

```
print(grad2)
print(xorTrainingWeights[1:3] - learningRate * grad2[1:3])
xorTrainingWeights[1:3] = xorTrainingWeights[1:3] - learningRate * grad2[1:3]
print(xorTrainingWeights[1:3])
```

Here the values of variables are:

```
xorTrainingWeights = np.array([1, 2, 3])
learningRate = 0.01
grad2 = np.dot(xorTrainingExamples.transpose(), delta2) / 4
```

The outputs for the print statements are as follows:

1st iteration:

```
[ 0.41579347  0.23752538  0.24488529]
[ 1.99762475  2.99755115]
[1 2]
```

2nd iteration:

```
[ 0.38661089  0.21570272  0.23364698]
[ 0.99784297  1.99766353]
[0 1]
```

So what exactly is wrong here. Even though I am subtracting the `grad2` which will be a small value when multiplied with `learningRate` the number is still being floored to the lowest integer.

Comment: So your question is that the result you expected to be floor turns out an integer?

Comment: Values are still incomplete what are the values of  `xorTrainingExamples` and `delta2`

Comment: @WrayZheng no....I asked why is the value being fllored..I have never used floor anywhere

Comment: @Dark is it necessary? i am subtracting the grad2 only and the value of  xorTrainingweights - grad2 is given by the print statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `xorTrainingWeights` has `dtype=int`, so your values are floored when you reassign.

Check this:

```
test = np.array([1,2,3])
print(test)
test[1:3] = test[1:3] - 0.001
print(test)

test = np.array([1.,2.,3.])
# or test = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=float)
# or test = test.astype(float)
print(test)
test[1:3] = test[1:3] - 0.001
print(test)
```

gives:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 1 2]
[ 1.  2.  3.]
[ 1.     1.999  2.999]
```

Comment: Good catch there.